# How to set the dTolerance parameter of sf::st_simplify()

Tags: r, sf

I am reading the help files of `sf::st_simplify()` function and I got this passage that confused me about how to set the `dTolerance` parameter:

> If you run st_simplify, the input data is specified with long-lat
> coordinates and sf_use_s2() returns TRUE, then the value of dTolerance
> must be specified in meters.

Does this make sense? Logic would lead me to believe that if my data is lon-lat and `s2` is in use, then distances are in degrees, not meters.

Comment: Degrees are time not distance so, somewhere in the background processing distance needs to be derived. This message is telling you that if your data is in lat/long and you are using the S2 Spherical Geometry library (s2) then you should provide this tolerance in meters. A standard conversion of degrees to distance is great circle which results in kilometers as the distance unit.